# Shutil not copying all files

Tags: python, copy, filesystems, shutil

I have a folder with files named like this:

```
Sheyenne_19840517.dat
Sheyenne_19840517.hdr
Sheyenne_19840704.dat
Sheyenne_19840704.hdr
Sheyenne_19840906.dat
Sheyenne_19840906.hdr
Sheyenne_19850520.dat
Sheyenne_19850520.hdr
Sheyenne_19850621.dat
Sheyenne_19850621.hdr
Sheyenne_19860726.dat
Sheyenne_19860726.hdr
Sheyenne_19860827.dat
Sheyenne_19860827.hdr
Sheyenne_19870830.dat
Sheyenne_19870830.hdr
Sheyenne_19870915.dat
Sheyenne_19870915.hdr
```

the numbers at the end of the file names represent the date.  I want to seperate the files by month.  So all files in May (or 05) get their own folder and so on.  I am trying to use this code right now:

```
import os
import shutil

hank_out=r'F:\Sheyenne\ROI\All_Sheyenne_julian\By_Month\NDVI'
pth=r'F:\Sheyenne\ROI\All_Sheyenne_julian\NDVI'

for f in os.listdir(pth):
    month=os.path.basename(f)[-8:-6]
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(hank_out,month)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(hank_out, month))
    shutil.copy(f, os.path.join(hank_out, month))
```

This only copies the first file encountered for a month.  So each folder only has one file in it for the output, and it is the file that is first encountered for that month.  I am not sure why ALL of the files are not being copied.

Comment: You never actually assign `destination_path`. Maybe that's just a typo in your post?

Comment: I do, and I fixed it, it was just an error when copying my code to here

Comment: probably also want to fix `dir_name` in the previous two lines as well

Comment: Also the indent level of the `shutil.copy` command is too far in and is only executed when the path doesn't exist. That's likely what's causing your issue.

Comment: Yep....so simple.  Thank you.